Simplifying an Infinite Sum for a Geometric Distribution
I am working on the following question:
Suppose $X$ ~ $Geometric(p)$. Find $E[\frac{1}{2^{X}}].$
I did the following: $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{x}}p(1-p)^{x-1} = \frac{1}{1-p} p \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}(\frac{(1-p)}{2})^{x}.$ How can I further simplify this and get rid of the summation?

Isn't that a Geometric progression with common ratio of $(1-p)/2$?

Step 1. Factor out constants
$E\left[\frac{1}{2^X}\right] = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^x} \cdot p \cdot (1-p)^{x-1} = p \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-p)^{x-1}}{2^x} = \frac{p}{2} \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1-p}{2}\right)^{x-1}$
Step 2. Recognize the geometric series
$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1-p}{2}\right)^{x-1} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1-p}{2}} = \frac{2}{1 + p}$
So that,
$$E\left[\frac{1}{2^X}\right] = \frac{p}{1 + p}$$

I see, this makes sense! Thank you, but I am confused on how you get $2^{x-1}.$ Could you elaborate on this part?

Ahh, I see $\frac{1}{2^{x}}$ $= \frac{1}{2}$  $\frac{1}{2^{x-1}}$, which then allows us to factor out $\frac{1}{2}$. Thanks so much!

Recall the Geometric series:
$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty r^x = \dfrac{r}{1-r}\qquad\text{when }\lvert r\rvert < 1$$
So when $r=\frac{1-p}2$ ...

Got it, thanks!
